# Parent file create child file (need some help on logic)

Tags: javascript, logic, xpages

Question :

Let say i have an application form that allow me to apply for few service.

for example services are :
Service A
Service B
Service C

Condition :

1. one application form only allow **one user** to add few service
2. Parent file is "application form"
3. Child file is "service 1", service 2, Service 3

user have 2 button to select either to click on "save" / "Cancel" at Application form(parent file)

My form allow to be save anytime.

My question, if user already add the child document, but user click on "cancel" function. Means it want to delete document(child) that been select on the time key in. How to differentiate it.

Answer (score 4):

A few approaches come to mind.

The first is to only allow creration of child documents in read mode. That splits the separation between creating the parents and the children.

The second is to have child documents get a "Draft" flag when initially created. If they save, clear the draft flag. If they cancel, remove drafts.

The third is similar. Capture which children exist when they first edit the document, then in the cancel process, remove them.

Steps 2 and 3 still have the problem that edits to an existing child will still be held. A fourth option is to load the children into Java objects that wrap the underlying Notes document. Creation will create the Java object, not the Notes Document. Save will then create or update the backend Notes documents. This way you're able to handle parent and child as a single transaction and this will be the most complete option. (DominoDocument datasource is effectively a Java class that's a wrapper of the backend Notes Document, so it's effectively the same thing, but covering multiple documents instead of one).